# Unable to find element using selenium webdriver for application on IE11. Tried CSSSelector,id,name and even class too but didn't resolved

Tags: selenium-webdriver

Unable to identify the *select* element using Selenium webdriver. Below is the html for *select* tag

```
<div class="scriptBlockP">Select DNIS: <select name="scriptContent$dnisDDL" id="scriptContent_dnisDDL">
    <option value="5917033">5917033</option>
    <option value="5917034">5917034</option>
    <option value="5917035">5917035</option>
```

.
.
.
      more than 200 options

```
    <option value="12345">12345 - Test Invalid Dnis</option>
    </select>
    </div>
```

Below is the code tried:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException,FileNotFoundException
{
  System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver","C:\\IEDriverServer.exe");
  WebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(); 
  WebElement e = null;

  try{ 
    driver.get("link");
    e = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='scriptContent_dnisDDL']"));
    List<WebElement> Campaign = e.findElements(By.tagName("option"));

    for ( int i =0;i< Campaign.size();i++ ) 
    { 
      String value = Campaign.get(i).getText(); System.out.println(value);
    }

  }
  catch(Exception ex){ 
    System.out.println(ex.getMessage()); 
  }
```

Comment: Can you post exactly what element you are trying to find? What is the error you see? what exactly you want? Please post the question correct

Comment: Which element are you trying to select ?

Comment: I have to select anyone of the value like 5917035. but I am getting an error "org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to find element with xpath/cssselector/id/name. I tried all ways to find element. latest I used the the code as

Comment: public static void main(String[] args)  throws InterruptedException, FileNotFoundException {
System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver","C:\\IEDriverServer.exe");
  WebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
  WebElement e = null;
  try{
  driver.get("link");
  e = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='scriptContent_dnisDDL']"));
  List<WebElement> Campaign = e.findElements(By.tagName("option"));
  for ( int i =0;i< Campaign.size();i++ )
  {
   String value = Campaign.get(i).getText();
   System.out.println(value);
  }
  }catch(Exception ex){
  System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
   
 }

Comment: I have posted an answer. Please try!

Comment: Please post you code in the question

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the Select class as follows:

```
Select dropdown = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("scriptContent_dnisDDL")));
```

To select its option say '5917035' you can do:

```
dropdown.selectByVisibleText("5917035"); //this one works best!
dropdown.selectByIndex(1);  
dropdown.selectByValue("5917035");
```

Comment: Can you please run this line: driver.getPageSource() and check if you have navigated to the page properly? Also, please post your code in your question..

Comment: It is important you post your code in your question and not in the comments section, that way others can easily try out your code. Did driver.getPageSource() return the proper web page?

Comment: How i will check whether page is navigated  properly or not and where should I place this  after driver.get();

Comment: Yes, after your driver.get(link) statement, print the driver.getPageSource() statement which will return the html source code of the page. Also, please go through the Selenium documentation.

Comment: it doesnt return any source code

driver.get("test.htm");
  driver.getPageSource();
  System.out.printf("get page :",driver.getPageSource());
  Select dropdown = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("scriptContent_dnisDDL")));
  dropdown.selectByVisibleText("5917001");

Answer (score 0):

Please verify whether the `select` element is present in any frame. If element is present in `iframe` tag, you need to switch the driver to frame using below code.

```
driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.id("<frame id>")));
```